# In reference to my variable of Ace, "ranAce" what would need to be performed for the while loop to function correctly in javascript?

Tags: javascript

in the "while loop" I have while the 2 random number arrays(for card 1 and card 2) and I am trying to say " While the number generator doesn't equal "ranAce" or the numbers"1,11"..Do this if no do this etc. When I run it, it doesn't run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Welcome to the arcade filled with MANY games");
var name = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase()
alert("Welcome "+name)
var select = prompt("1. Start Game \n \n 2. Instructions \n \n select: ")
if (select ==1)
    start()
else if (select ==2)
    instructions()


function menu() {
    var select = prompt("1. Start Game \n \n 2. Instructions \n \n select: ")
    if (select ==1)
        start()
    else if (select ==2)
        instructions()
}
function start() {
    var option = prompt("1. Black Jack \n \n To end, type QUIT \n \n Select: ").toUpperCase()
    if (option ==1)
        goFish()
    else if (option ==2)
        blackJack()
    else if (option =="QUIT")
        menu()



}
function blackJack() {
    alert("Welcome to Black Jack!")
    jack = 10
    queen = 10
    king = 10
    var ace = ["1", "11"]
    var ranAce = Math.floor(Math.random() *ace.length)
    var cards = ["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",jack,queen,king,ranAce]
    var cardsTwo = [2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",jack,queen,king,ranAce]
    var cardHit = [2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",jack,queen,king,ranAce]
    var ranCards = Math.floor(Math.random() *cards.length);
    var ranTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() *cardsTwo.length);
    var ranHit = Math.floor(Math.random() *cardsTwo.length);
    var add = (ranCards + ranTwo)
    while (ranCards && ranTwo != ranAce) 
        var add = (ranCards + ranTwo)
        if (add >21)
            var gameOver = prompt("You BUSTED! Game Over! Do you want to play again? YES OR NO").toUpperCase()
            if (game =="YES")
                blackJack()
            else if (gameOver =="NO")
                menu()

        var userCards = prompt(ranCards+" and "+ranTwo+" do you want to HIT or STAY?").toUpperCase()
        if (userCards =="HIT")
        var add2 = (add + ranHit) 
        if (add2 >21)
            var gameOver = prompt("You BUSTED! Game Over! Do you want to play again? YES OR NO").toUpperCase()
            if (game =="YES")
                blackJack()
            else if (gameOver =="NO")
                menu()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```js
var cardsTwo = [2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",jack,queen,king,ranAce]
var cardHit = [2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",jack,queen,king,ranAce]
```

You are missing " after the first [

Comment: I configured the syntax error to disappear for that part by adding the quotations, but when I get the part of the game "Black Jack", I press 1 and it does not prompt the game itself. Is there something else wrong throughout the code?

Comment: It is probably the while loop, not sure where exactly.

Comment: I know I haven't fully finished the while loop in any way, but I didn't want to keep going if it was not running up to this point.

Comment: You miss { }  after while. So var add = (ranCards + ranTwo); is executing everythime.

Comment: while (ranCards && ranTwo != ranAce) { } (<-- Right here, then put everything for my while loop in that, correct?)

Comment: Yes, put inside { } what you want to run in loop.

Comment: You did not provide goFish function, so I can't test whole process

Comment: Oh, that was from earlier, it was supposed to have multiple games, I decided to take away GoFish for now, this is why it would not prompt the game itself, I understand, I must change the number for Black Jack so then it will prompt the game. I see now. Let me test it.

Comment: Is everything OK?